# What is the defualt DATE_FORMATS format in Time and DateTime in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I'm sending DateTimes to PHP developer and he wanted to know which format the date strings are in. I know how to specify to use iso8601 but instead I'm trying to figure out what the default one is when no format is set. But I cannot figure it out.

The conversion happen in https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/conversions.rb

```
  DATE_FORMATS = {
    :db           => '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
    :number       => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S',
    :nsec         => '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%9N',
    :time         => '%H:%M',
    :short        => '%d %b %H:%M',
    :long         => '%B %d, %Y %H:%M',
    :long_ordinal => lambda { |time|
      day_format = ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(time.day)
      time.strftime("%B #{day_format}, %Y %H:%M")
    },
    :rfc822       => lambda { |time|
      offset_format = time.formatted_offset(false)
      time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S #{offset_format}")
    },
    :iso8601      => lambda { |time| time.iso8601 }
  }

  def to_formatted_s(format = :default)
    if formatter = DATE_FORMATS[format]
      formatter.respond_to?(:call) ? formatter.call(self).to_s : strftime(formatter)
    else
      to_default_s
    end
  end
  alias_method :to_default_s, :to_s
  alias_method :to_s, :to_formatted_s
```

Since `DATE_FORMATS` is a hash without the key `:default` it returns `nil` which makes the if-statement call `to_default_s` which is an alias for `to_s` which in turn is an alias for `to_formatted_s` and we have a recursion...

Something is not right in my analysis so please help me sort this out. Am I missing something really fundamental? And why is it not documented anywhere what the default format is?

Comment: check this: [Standard rails-i18n locale](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-US.yml)

Comment: @GaganGami I guess you refer to line 202 there. How does that come in? Tried to search the i18n gem for DATE_FORMATS to see if it was added to the hash but no. And neither can find that it is added in a newly created rails app. And when using i18n you always need to use its translation or localisation methods, e.g. `I18n.l Time.now` And just to check I did both  `I18n.l DateTime.now => "Thu, 23 Apr 2015 15:06:09 +0200"` and  `DateTime.now.to_formatted_s => "2015-04-23T15:06:24+02:00"`. As you see these two did not generate the same result so that is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can tell is that `to_default_s` aliases to Ruby's `to_s`.  For the Time class that is here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Time.html#method-i-to_s

The relevant bit from that method is below which defines the default format (at least for ruby 2.2.1).

```
if (TIME_UTC_P(tobj))
    return strftimev("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC", time, rb_usascii_encoding());
else
    return strftimev("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z", time, rb_usascii_encoding());
```

That all said... my advice would be to forcibly convert it to iso8601 format so you know it won't randomly change at some point.

Comment: Aah, I missed two things in my analysis. First regarding `alias_method`. According to the docs http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/alias_method makes a copy of the method name. So what happens is that the `to_s` is copied to `to_default_s` and then `to_s` is overwritten by `to_formatted_s`. Secondly I forgot about ruby's open class it is the ruby Time class that is being added methods to. Thanks!